# error deployment vercel, next-auth, and nextjs v13.4

Tags: next.js, deployment, vercel, next-auth

Every time I try to deploy any project on vercel using next-auth google or github I got 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT. the project works well on localhost but not when deploying it on vercel I already update the authrization url in console google cloud

I don't know how to solve this problem.